# Angular Velocity in the context of projectile motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, angular-velocity

I recently faced this problem in a test:

> Two particles A & B are projected from top of two towers of height $300$ m and $600$ m with velocity $50 \ \textrm{m/s}$ and $250 \ \textrm{m/s}$ respectively. What is the angular velocity of B w.r.t A?

[image: image provided with the question for reference]

A similar question often appears in question-banks asking to find the distance between the towers, but this is something different. How do I even approach this problem? What does it mean by *angular velocity* of B in this context? I don't see any circular motion taking place here.

Please guide me how to approach the problem.

Comment: Find the velocity of B in the frame of A, and then you can find the tangential and then angular velocity.

Comment: @VincentThacker If I am understanding this correctly, the angular velocity should be then $\omega_\textrm{B/A} = \frac{v_\textrm{B/A}}{\textrm{height of tower B}} \textrm{rad/sec}$, but now I am confused on what should be $v_\textrm{B/A}$. Shouldn't it be $v_\textrm{B} - (-v_\textrm{A} \cos 30^{\circ})$? Plugging in that value is not matching with any of the given options.

Comment: Okay, maybe I wasn't clear enough. So in the frame of B, you need to find the position and velocity of A. From the position, you can define orthogonal radial and tangential vectors. Then find the tangential component of velocity and dividing that by the radius gives you the angular velocity. Or you could just take the shortcut and use the definition of angular velocity as $\boldsymbol{\omega} = \mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{v}/r^2$ (though in this case, the direction isn't important).

Comment: @VincentThacker You said I need to find the velocity of B in the frame of A, so shouldn't that be $\vec{v_\textrm{B}} - \vec{v_\textrm{A}}$? I get that the angular velocity will the component of $\vec{v_\textrm{B/A}}$ perpendicular to $h_\textrm{B}$ divided by $h_\textrm{B}$. I just looked up the official solutions for the test and it just says $\omega = \frac{125}{600} \textrm{rad/sec}$. I can understand that 600 is the height of the tower but I can't figure out how are they getting to the value '125'.

Comment: Yes to your first question. The position of B relative to A is $300$ in the vertical direction and $300\sqrt{3}$ in the horizontal direction, which is 30° above the horizon. The 600 comes from the fact that B is 600 m from A. It has nothing to do with the height of the tower. Your usage of $h_\text{B}$ is wrong. It should be replaced with the vector I mentioned above.